# Where are the paragon stones and the paragon portal?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

UESPWiki mentions paragon stones and a portal in [Forgotten Vale](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forgotten_Vale), but I haven't been been able to find even one stone or the portal. Where can they be found? I would prefer directions from nearby shrines or other easily found location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This video has good directions to the paragon stones and the portal.

This one briskly shows what the different rewards are.